# How to change the cursor hoving on a datatable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

The default cursor is a hand when hoving the mouse on the table. You can see in [the simple demo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) of the offical document.

How can I change it to an arrow? The little hand implies that when you click on a row something will happen, which is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a feature request for this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70755

In the comments, [someone mentioned a workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70755#issuecomment-812469497), which is basically wrapping the whole DataTable into an IgnorePointer widget:

```
IgnorePointer(
   child: DataTable(
     headingRowHeight: 0,
     showCheckboxColumn: false,
     columns: [DataColumn(label: Container()), DataColumn(label: Container())],
     rows: [...]
   ),
);
```

It might have some drawbacks depending on your use case, but definitely working for now.

Answer (score 0):

put dataTable inside AbsorbPointer()

Comment: But I have a button in each datarow. How to use arrow cursor all over the table except the buttons in it?

Comment: in this case you need to customize dataTable